# How to kill a Windows Process through a WPF ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am a WPF newbee trying to build my own Windows Task Manager.
Right now i have a window with all the active processes running on my machine showing in a `ListView`.

Now here is my problem: I have a button called `End Process`. I want to select a process from the `ListView` and kill it by pressing the `End Process` button. I just cant figure it out how to do that.

I have this code (C#) assigned to the button:

```
private void End_Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process[] procs=Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessesListView.SelectedItem.ToString());    
    foreach (Process p in procs)
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's it not doing correctly?

Comment: Your code kills all processes with the same *name* as the selected item. Just to make sure that you kill the *right* process use the process ID as the identifier.

Comment: Tnx for quick respone. In fact it's not doing anything. As if the button not connected to anything. (MessageBox is working fine though)

Comment: Will the debugger hit a break point in the method? Is the process actually killed (check with Task Manager) and your list is just not updating? What do you mean by "MessageBox is working fine though"? I see no `MessageBox`. What is the `ToString` value of `SelectedItem` It may be different than what you are expecting and `GetProcessesByName` is not finding anything.

Comment: 1. There is no breaking, the program is running without exceptions. 2) The process is not killed (i am doing it with notepad to be sure).  3) I mentioned the MessageBox to eliminate the possibility that the button is not triggering the correct method, you can ignore it, its not there anymore.  4) The **ToString** value is probably the problem. When i use "MessageBox" to check it, i see the full path like: **System.Diagnostics...... (Explorer)**.  Do you have any advice as to how can i get only **Explorer** name without the prefix? Or how can i use the "ProcessId"?  Tnx a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the items in your list are the actual `Process` objects. If so, you can do something like this:

```
private void End_Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Process process = (Process)ProcessesListView.SelectedItem;
  process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Wow, 10 minutes on StackOverflow solved me a 2 day headache :)  Thanks a lot! Works perfectly...